# Antecedent of "clear" in "lower ball onto wood blocks with the plates clear"

Tags: adjectives, antecedents

This sentence is taken from valve instructions:

> Lower ball onto wood blocks with the plates clear, and remove the plates from the ball.

What does the word *clear* refer to? Plates? Can someone explain this sentence a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume from the context that it either means free from obstruction, or clearly visible.

The alternative would be 'transparent', but I can't see that being a likely contender.

Comment: Can I use it as an adverb in this case? I know it is a simple word , but considering the whole translation (not just this sent.) it just doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: The adverb of clear is 'clearly'. You'd have to relate it to an attribute of the plates. I can't see how you'd do that.